# Let G be k-reguler bipartite graph of degree at least 2. show that K(G) not equal 1?

Tags: graphs

Let G be k-reguler bipartite graph of degree at least 2, for all v belong to V(G) prove that k(G-v) is connected?

Comment: What is your function $k(G-v)$? Do you mean $G\setminus \{v\}$? And you can use $\LaTeX$ to format your equations.

Comment: K(G) means the connectivity of a graph G, so K(G-v) or K(G\{v}) the same

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried? We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: You also need $G$ to be connected to begin with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure mathematics homework question with no computational content.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. Here is a counterexample. Let $E$ be the even numbers and $O$ be the odd numbers, and Let $N=\{(n,n+1)|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $G=(E\cup O, N)$ is a $2$-regular, bipartite graphs, every vertex of which is a cut-vertex.

I won't do your homework for you until you can show where you get stuck, but I'll give you a hint: the conjecture is true for *finite* graphs, and the proof hinges on this fact. You say, *well the resulting components have some number of vertices, and these vertices of one component are distributed between the partitions, so I can count the number of edge ends on either side of the partitions* and then you double check if it comes out to the same. It also hinges on the fact that the two partitions are equally big: for a $k$-regular graph $G=(U\cup V, E)$, $|U|=|V|$, a fact which you will have to prove first. The proof for that hinges on the fact that the graph is regular.